# How to find solution of this equation $Y=x\cos x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How to find solution of this equation 
$$Y=x\cos x$$  in here $Y \in \mathbb{R}$

I tried to many way but it does works out, is it possible to resolve it?

Comment: I mean the formula of solution

Comment: What about numerical methods?

Comment: Mathematica cannot solve it for $Y=7$, so I doubt a solution exists in general. It is easy to see with IVT that solutions exist for all $Y$, so you can definitely get an arbitrarily good estimation.

Comment: I suppose that you want to solve for $x$ the equation
$$x\cos x=Y$$
where $Y$ is a real number. It seems that there is no closed form, so for particular values of $Y$ you can use some numerical method in order to estimate the solution(s).

Comment: i want to find roots for this equation by coding,  may be the idea of numerical method is the  good choice but i don't know how to code, can you help me?

Comment: Every $Y\in \mathbb{R}$ has infinitely many solutions $x\in \mathbb{R}$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ic5vn4k5ly

Comment: A good way to get closer to an answer is defining $f(x)=xcos(x)-Y$ and try to solve $f(x)=0$. For each $Y\in\mathbb{R}$ you can find infinite zeros by numerical methods (for example, $Y=2$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%3Dx*cos(x)-2).

Comment: What could be interesting would be to find the first positive root of the equation.

Comment: Newton´s method: http://faculty.swosu.edu/michael.dougherty/calc1/MD5-5.pdf and https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=using+Newton%27s+method+solve+x+cos+x+%3D+0&lk=3